# group by id1 and id2 and apply a function using another dataframe and dates

Tags: python, pandas, function, date

My problem is the following:
I have a dataframe **DF1** of car accidents (**id_accident**) and PASSENGER victims (**id_victim**)  and the date of the accident (**date1**).

| id_accident | id_victim | date_accident | ROL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 23A | 2021/20/01 | PASSENGER |
| 456 | 12B | 2020/19/08 | PASSENGER |
| 111 | 41A | 2021/20/01 | PASSENGER |
| 222 | 54B | 2020/19/08 | PASSENGER |

I have another dataframe **DF2** of the same car accidents and more (**id_accident**) and VICTIMS in general (could be **ROLE_VICTIM** = PASSENGER or DRIVERS) and the date of the accident (**date1**)

| id_accident | id_victim | date_accident | ROL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 23A | 2020/20/19 | PASSENGER |
| 002 | 12B | 2019/31/12 | DRIVER |
| 003 | 41A | 2020/20/12 | PASSENGER |
| 004 | 54B | 2020/20/07 | DRIVER |

So, I need to find **for each id_accident and id_passenger** if this passenger had a previous accident within last 3 months but now as ROLE_VICTIM =DRIVER.

My code consists in two loops and a function that searches the previous accidents when the victim of this accident was a driver in the previous one.

```
def siniestros_anteriores(DF2,dni_victima,date_accident):

result = DF2.loc[(DF2.siniestro_fecha_ocurrencia >= date_accident-  pd.Timedelta(90, unit='d')) &
                (DF2.siniestro_fecha_ocurrencia < date_accident) &
      (DF2.poreservable_victima_dni == dni_victima) & 
      (DF2.poreservable_victima_condicion_desc =="DRIVER")] 

    if result.shape[0]==0:# si no encuentra nada--> no se activa la regla
    return 0
else:
    return 1

for id_sin in DF1.siniestro_id.unique():
    df = DF1.loc[DF1.siniestro_id ==id_sin,:]
    date_accident= df.loc[df.siniestro_id==id_sin,'siniestro_fecha_ocurrencia'].values[0]
    for dni in df.poreservable_victima_dni.unique():
        if (dni == "?") | (pd.isna(dni)):# si no hay dni--> directamente la regla es 0
            result = [id_sin, dni, 0] 
        else:
            r = siniestros_anteriores(DF2,dni,date_accident)
            result = [id_sin,dni,r]
    results.append(result)
```

Is there an efficient way of solving this problem? Maybe doing a groupby + apply... but it is not working...  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post data sampleas as text? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @crayxt I've just edited it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like classic SQL question. What kind of output format do you need?

I had to change first date if DF2 to `2020/20/01` to make pandas recognize it.
Below is the complete example using `pd.merge`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from io import StringIO

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""id_accident   id_victim   date_accident   ROL
123     23A     2021/20/01  PASSENGER
456     12B     2020/19/08  PASSENGER
111     41A     2021/20/01  PASSENGER
222     54B     2020/19/08  PASSENGER"""), sep="\s+", parse_dates=["date_accident"], dayfirst=True)


df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""id_accident   id_victim   date_accident   ROL
001     23A     2020/20/09  PASSENGER
002     12B     2019/31/12  DRIVER
003     41A     2020/20/12  PASSENGER
004     54B     2020/20/07  DRIVER"""), sep="\s+", parse_dates=["date_accident"], dayfirst=True)

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on="id_victim")
```

Now df3 is equal to

```
   id_accident_x id_victim date_accident_x      ROL_x  id_accident_y date_accident_y      ROL_y
0            123       23A      2021/20/01  PASSENGER              1      2020/20/19  PASSENGER
1            456       12B      2020/19/08  PASSENGER              2      2019/31/12     DRIVER
2            111       41A      2021/20/01  PASSENGER              3      2020/20/12  PASSENGER
3            222       54B      2020/19/08  PASSENGER              4      2020/20/07     DRIVER
```

And to filter out by your condition

```
>>> df3[(df3.ROL_x == "PASSENGER") & (df3.ROL_y == "DRIVER") & ((df3.date_accident_y - df3.date_accident_y).dt.days < 90)]
   id_accident_x id_victim date_accident_x      ROL_x  id_accident_y date_accident_y   ROL_y
1            456       12B      2020-08-19  PASSENGER              2      2019-12-31  DRIVER
3            222       54B      2020-08-19  PASSENGER              4      2020-07-20  DRIVER
```